# Birdseye Weebly theme- Make mobile logo larger and centered

Tags: css, weebly

I dabble in coding and am working on a Weebly Birdseye website. The logo looks great on desktop but is tiny in the mobile header. I would like it to be larger and centered. Any advice is appreciated! Here is the CSS for the Header (first the desktop site and then the mobile site):

```
/* Header */
.birdseye-header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 12;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}
.birdseye-header .container {
  display: table;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.birdseye-header label.hamburger {
  display: none;
}
.birdseye-header .logo {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
.birdseye-header .logo a {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
}
.birdseye-header .logo img {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 300px;
}

 /* Header */
  .birdseye-header {
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 248, 220, 0.95);
  }
  .birdseye-header .logo {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 8px;
  }
  .birdseye-header .logo a {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
  }
  .birdseye-header .logo img {
    max-height: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .birdseye-header .logo #wsite-title {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
    line-height: 1.4em !important;
  }
  .birdseye-header .container {
    min-height: 40px;}
```

Comment: Mobile vs Desktop -> the answer involves media queries. Can you give us a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already changed the .birdseye-header .container { from max-height: 80px; to max-height: 100%; so that's a good start.

The Media Screen...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
 .birdseye-header .birdseye-header, .birdseye-header .logo, .birdseye-header .logo img {
    max-height: 40px;
 }
}
```

...causes the Image to shrink, so you would need to increate the max-height: 40px; to your preferred pixel size. Maybe something like 80px

**However, I should note that the .banner-wrap .container padding may need to be/should also be altered from 60px to what ever the height of the logo is.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
 .banner-wrap .container {
     padding: 60px 20px;
 }
}
```

---

As for centering the Logo, you should be able to do something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
 .birdseye-header .logo img {
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
}
```